# Applying Change of Variables theorem to two Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Consider the following formula, for $X,Y$ nonnegative random variables with joint pdf $h$:
$$
P(X \leq Y) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^y h(x,y) \, dx dy.
$$
I thought I'd try to show this more rigorously using change of variables theorem and other results from measure theory, and I'd appreciate any critiques.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space on which the nonnegative random variables $X$ and $Y$ are defined with joint continuous pdf $h$.  Denote by $\Lambda$ the distribution measure of the random vector $(X,Y)$, by $m^2$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and by $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.   Finally, let
$$
A = \{(x,y) \in [0,\infty) \times [0,\infty) : x \leq y\}.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
P(X \leq Y) & = P((X,Y)^{-1}(A)) \\
& = \int_{(X,Y)^{-1}(A)} \, P(d \omega) \\
& = \int_A \Lambda(dx, dy) \\
& = \int_A h(x,y)\,  m^2(dx, dy) \\
& = \int_0^\infty \int_0^y h(x,y) \, m(dx) m(dy) \\
& = \int_0^\infty \int_0^y h(x,y) \, dx dy.
\end{align*}
The first equality is just rewriting the set $\{X \leq Y\}$, the second is by definition of the Lebesgue integral of $(X,Y)^{-1}(A)$, the third is by the change of variables theorem, the fourth is because $h$ is a Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\Lambda$ w.r.t. $m^2$, the fifth is due to Tonelli's theorem, and the final equality is due to the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals agreeing since $h$ is continuous.

Comment: The formula refers to Lebesgue integral hence your last step (coming back to Riemann) is (unwarranted and) unneeded (no, a PDF needs not be continuous). Apart from that, this is indeed how one can prove the formula if one does not wish to consider it as a simple consequence of the definition.

Comment: @Did Thanks.  Is the notation $(X,Y)^{-1}(A)$ standard?  I haven't come across it before but I'm unsure how else to write it.

Comment: Indeed, since $A\subset\color{red}{\mathbb R^2}$ and $(X,Y):\Omega\to\color{red}{\mathbb R^2}$ hence $(X,Y)^{-1}(A)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid(X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in A\}$.